# About a function in homogeneous Sobolev spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Assume there is a Sobolev function $f\in D^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^2)\cap D^{2,1}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, in another word $\nabla f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $\nabla^2 f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. What can we say about $f$ ?

Can we deduce that $f$ has a limit at infinity? i.e. $\lim\limits_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)$ exists.

Generally speaking, under what condition in Sobolev spaces a function would have a limit at infinity?

Comment: I guess $W$ is more standard than $D$ here. Anyway, $W^{2,1}$ is a subset of $W^{1,2}$ by Sobolev embedding, so there's no need to assume $f \in W^{1,2}$.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz: No, D and W denote homogeneous and inhomogeneous Soblev spaces, respectively. They are different.

Answer (score 1):

By Theorem 4.12 in Adams and Fournier's book *Sobolev spaces*, $W^{2,1}(\mathbb R^2)$ embeds into $C_0(\mathbb R^2)$ (and in general $W^{n,1}(\mathbb R^n)$ embeds into $C_0(\mathbb R^n)$), so the answer is *yes*.

The proof goes like this. By taking the second-order Taylor expansion with integral remainder and integrating it with respect to the point of expansion (not the point of evaluation), we show the estimate
$$
\| u \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^2)} \le C \| u \|_{W^{2,1}(\mathbb R^2)} 
\quad \text{for } u \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^2).
$$
Since $W^{2,1}$ is the closure of $C_c^\infty$ in $W^{2,1}$-norm, the above estimate implies that $W^{2,1}$ is contained in the closure of $C_c^\infty$ in $L^\infty$-norm, i.e., in the space 
$$
C_0(\mathbb R^2) = \{ u \in C(\mathbb R^2) : u(x) \to 0 \text{ when } x \to \infty \}.
$$

Comment: I can see this, but what about $D^{2,1}$ functions?

Comment: OK, now I know what you mean (thank you, StarBug). I'm not familiar with homogeneous Sobolev spaces, but I believe a similar argument should work.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this question is not difficult. For any smooth function with compact support, it holds that

$$u(x_{1},x_{2})=\int_{-\infty}^{x_{1}}\int_{-\infty}^{x_{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial{x_{1}}\partial{x_{2}}}(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{1}dy_{2}$$

Hence, $||u||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2})}\leq C||\nabla^{2}u||_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2})}$. Then by approximation this is also true for $D^{2,1}$ function, and one has obtained the embedding $D^{2,1}\subset C_{0}$. The existence of limit at infinity is an easy corollary.

Comment: Could you give us some more details?

Comment: @StarBug Thank you for your attention. I have updated my answer. Comments are welcome!

Comment: Are you arguing that all $D^{2,1}$ functions a bounded (in $L^\infty$)? But what about polynomials of order 1. For example: $u(x_1,x_2)=x_1$. This is surely a  $D^{2,1}$ function that is not bounded.

Comment: @StarBug Sorry, I guess it should be $u-P$ on the left where $P$ is a  polynomial determined by $u$.

Comment: But even if you can show that  $u-P\in L^{\infty}$ for some polynomial, how do you obtain an answer to your original question whether $u$ has a limit at infinity? You have to somehow also exploit that $u\in D^{1,2}$ I guess.

Comment: @StarBug Thank you. My answer only works for $W^{2,1}$ function.